# include Matlab Coder dll in Android Studio

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, dll, android-ndk

I have an image processing `Matlab Algorithm` and want to deploy it on android. I convert Matlab codes to c++ and use generated native codes on Android OS by NDK.
Now my matlab coder use header files of dll.
[matlab coder output files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS9G8.png)
How can I include these files in my Android Studio project? I search and found windows dll can't run on Android. if this is right for my problem, Is there any way which say to `Matlab Coder` doesn't use dll ?

Comment: The libraries you used could be available for Android. Or you have the source code of the libraries, then you could compile them for Android. Or you try to get rid of those libraries. Do you really need them?

Comment: Why they downgrade the question?! declare the reason so I can edit the question??

Comment: How can they be available for android? they are Matlab 2016a dll. Are they open source? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following documentation link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/understanding-code-generation-with-image-processing-toolbox.html

Also see the beginning of the following page:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/list-of-supported-functions-with-usage-notes.html

You should try a hardware target different than "MATLAB Host Computer". When targeting "MATLAB Host Computer" if there is a platform specific shared library implementation available for the image processing function it is used. But for other targets coder will use a standalone c-code implementation for the function if it is available.

Comment: I generated code files without dll by selecting ARM as hardware target